# Android Studio 2.3.3 Appium issue

Tags: android, appium

```
package com.example.ibm_admin.appiumapplication;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
//import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;



public class Calculator {
   public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
        //Set up desired capabilities and pass the Android app-activity and app-package to Appium
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "5.1.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Galaxy On7");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");


        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
// This package name of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator"); // This is Launcher activity of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
//Create RemoteWebDriver instance and connect to the Appium server
        //It will launch the Calculator App in Android Device using the configurations specified in Desired Capabilities
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCal() throws Exception {
        //locate the Text on the calculator by using By.name()
        WebElement two=driver.findElement(By.name("2"));
        two.click();
        WebElement plus=driver.findElement(By.name("+"));
        plus.click();
        WebElement four=driver.findElement(By.name("4"));
        four.click();
        WebElement equalTo=driver.findElement(By.name("="));
        equalTo.click();
        //locate the edit box of the calculator by using By.tagName()
        WebElement results=driver.findElement(By.tagName("EditText"));
        //Check the calculated value on the edit box
        assert results.getText().equals("6"):"Actual value is : "+results.getText()+" did not match with expected value: 6";

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void teardown(){
        //close the app
        driver.quit();
    }
```

## }

I am running Appium script using android studio, want to launch calculator and perform some basic action(script for the same mentioned above) 
Configuration details:
Mobile: Android Galaxy On7 version 5.1.1

=======================================================================

## Error Message which I am getting on Andriod console mentioned below:

"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\bin" -Didea.junit.sm_runner -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\data\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\build\intermediates\classes\test\debug;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\cssparser-0.9.20.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\gson-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\f5e11fb9a80aecc042b1e5a0a008e22616eef103\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\f5e11fb9a80aecc042b1e5a0a008e22616eef103\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\serializer-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\httpclient-4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\htmlunit-core-js-2.23.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\neko-htmlunit-2.23.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\31ed20e205fe04e88f6f9c1d682c13d2177bc509\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\31ed20e205fe04e88f6f9c1d682c13d2177bc509\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\2fe2ad2b678efc4ad73f69c8a3492615bd8c329d\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\2fe2ad2b678efc4ad73f69c8a3492615bd8c329d\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\websocket-client-9.2.15.v20160210.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\jna-platform-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\25.3.1\support-annotations-25.3.1.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\b99db0eff410f981260c96c15666c5f8fe9a49ab\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\b99db0eff410f981260c96c15666c5f8fe9a49ab\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\phantomjsdriver-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\44bed11ecf8df53c9723650ed9ff51385b015d22\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\44bed11ecf8df53c9723650ed9ff51385b015d22\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\netty-3.5.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\xalan-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\4e891577e853101408c8d4643249ea1f5e61aaeb\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\4e891577e853101408c8d4643249ea1f5e61aaeb\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\jetty-util-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\websocket-api-9.2.15.v20160210.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\56dfe4f79683d5a268a8fd83c825385ee11d17fa\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\56dfe4f79683d5a268a8fd83c825385ee11d17fa\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\786a62bf30d44d628103e6d67d25594af339666b\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\786a62bf30d44d628103e6d67d25594af339666b\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\websocket-common-9.2.15.v20160210.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\htmlunit-2.23.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\jna-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\de3291f937c3d61774b897952ccc113f29a25f23\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\de3291f937c3d61774b897952ccc113f29a25f23\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\4a692d1d348a979cd770289fdfe056689d947924\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\4a692d1d348a979cd770289fdfe056689d947924\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\java-client-4.14.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\httpmime-4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\guava-19.0.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\m2repository\com\android\support\constraint\constraint-layout-solver\1.0.2\constraint-layout-solver-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\httpcore-4.4.4.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\libs\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\584b968c37726e3ea7b73a3cc08f74a47959bd80\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\584b968c37726e3ea7b73a3cc08f74a47959bd80\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\3b2edeb370f0e07064b0570bcce8b89a5d8dc9c6\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\3b2edeb370f0e07064b0570bcce8b89a5d8dc9c6\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\6462712a35fa855d973b09af396f58c2f8321516\output\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.android\build-cache\6462712a35fa855d973b09af396f58c2f8321516\output\res;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\build\intermediates\sourceFolderJavaResources\test\debug;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\app\build\intermediates\sourceFolderJavaResources\debug;C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumApplication\build\generated\mockable-android-25.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 com.example.ibm_admin.appiumapplication.CalculatorTest
Jul 12, 2017 9:44:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'IBM372-PC09Z6VS', ip: '192.168.1.5', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_112-release'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:161)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
at com.example.ibm_admin.appiumapplication.CalculatorTest.setUp(CalculatorTest.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Test ignored.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.ibm_admin.appiumapplication.CalculatorTest.End(CalculatorTest.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code -1

Comment: please ask if some additional details required

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, in this case I think we have far too much detail! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Copy/Pasting everything into a question and hoping for an answer is not a great strategy!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is particularly relevant

Comment: sure, as I am new so learning how I should ask question on stake overflow

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrestled with that well-known example for some time before coming up with my own variation.  The actual driver creation is shown as a method below, and the driver type becomes AndroidDriver:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class AppiumUtils {

    public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = null;


    public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> connectByPackageActivity(String deviceName, 
                                                                  String appPackage, 
                                                                  String appActivity) {

        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, deviceName);
        capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, appPackage);
        capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, appActivity);

        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL(url), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (SessionNotCreatedException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to create Appium session");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return driver;

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Bill, When I am using above suggested line of code then getting error message "can not resolve symbol AndroidElement" and same error for others MobileCapabilityType,AndroidMobileCapabilityType, I am using android studio 2.3.3 and appium server version 1.4.13.1

Comment: I've modified my existing code to include what I believe are the necessary imports - my class contains a lot of other methods and I only wanted to show that particular one, so there might be an import or two there that aren't necessary.  For future reference, you should be able to resolve the missing imports within Eclipse, if that's what you're using, by hovering the mouse over the highlighted error and selected the option to add the imports.